# Pre-Migration Risk Assessment - Vim to Neovim (2of8)

Tags: neovim, gvim

*(Shared preamble)*

With my pending adoption of Ubuntu MATE 22.04, I am looking primarily at [neovim](/questions/tagged/neovim), with possible adaptation as [spacevim](/questions/tagged/spacevim)/[lunarvim](/questions/tagged/lunarvim).  I am **very** comfortable with Vim, but am looking for a proper [ide](/questions/tagged/ide) layer for that tool of choice (want to do some [python](/questions/tagged/python) for CAD, [prolog](/questions/tagged/prolog) for personal medical), and it **seems** from what I have come across that Neovim is the way to go.

I want to make sure that I don't jump out of the frying pan into the fire.

Are there any **gotchas** that someone evaluating such a transition needs to know **before making the move**?  Specifically ...

**[2]** What things are *not* portable from Vim to Neovim ?

**Please Note:** I would ask that you please include the description of what is lacking/broken, along with the specific sequence to follow to reproduce the failed condition.  That way, all can independantly re-confirm, ensuring all risks associated with the migration are made explicit and facts are reliable for decision-making.